# error 2003(HY000) Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Tags: mysql, windows-services, localhost

This question may be a duplicate. I searched similar question, but the solutions of those problems did not help me fix the problem.

When I open mysql cmd line It asks me for password. Anyhow i did not set password to the server during configuration. So I just hit ENTER when it asks for password(it works on my Classmates' PCs), after I do that, an error message is displayed: error 2003(HY000) Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061).

So I thought there must be some problem with the windows service for mysql. I found out that the service was not running, so I tried to manually start the service, When I did so I got an error message: windows could not start the mysql service on local computer Error:193: 0xc1.

What Can I do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the windows service for mysql  running for not.If not running start it from services as administrator.
You can resolve this in a better way by starting service {mysql56} from command line as Administrator

net start mysql56

Second method

1. Check path to execute also check in registry also From Run type
   services.msc
2. Select mysql56(mysqlxx) right click and check
       properties and note down path to execute
3. From Run type regedit and
       navigate to

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\
4. Select the mysql service (mysqlxx) and check its ImagePath value
       data as same as path to execute
5. If it is not change it

Comment: Check the services from task manager or from administrative tools in control panel.Check the services name for mysql server version (ie mysqlxx) if that is not running,start the service by right clicking